# Plastic CSM makes any new item added as "private"

Tags: unity-game-engine, plasticscm

every folder and file I add to my unity project (.cs files, folders, sprites, etc..) becomes Private, and I have to manually right click and click on Add To source control to be downloadable for other contributors.

why is like that? how can newly added folder/assets be controlled by default?

Answer (score 0):

When you create new items in a Plastic workspace, they won't be added to source control by default. You will need to explicitly do it so Plastic is able to track them.

In the Plastic GUI preferences --> Other options, you can enable: "Checkin files when adding them to source control".
This way, when you add some items to source control, you don't need to perform the extra step of checkin.